# How can I connect an ESP32 to a power supply module?

Tags: esp32

I'm wondering how to connect my ESP to electricity without USB. I would like to use a power supply module. I haven't found any such solution.

The program on my ESP32 creates a web server on which it displays data from sensors and connects to my WiFi. Everything works fine when the ESP is connected to the USB port. When I connect the power supply module 5V - VIN and GND - GND. The LED shows that the power is on, but the ESP32 board does not connect to WiFi. I've attached a photo of the wanton below.

[image]

Comment: the vin pin on those modules (i have several) is actually mislabeled, test the voltage on it when plugged into usb; it SHOULD be 4.4-5.0v, but it's not. the only thing you can do is supply 3.3v of external power to the 3.3v pin.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems.

The first is this thing:

[image]

9V batteries don't do well when asked to supply large currents.  The ESP32 doesn't draw much current - except for when the WiFi is active.  The WiFi transmitter draws relatively large currents in bursts.  The 9V battery won't be able to supply the needed current - the WiFi transmitter won't work properly and won't be able to connect.

Not helping things is that you have the ESP32 and the voltage regulator at opposite ends of two breadboards.  Each connection adds some resistance, reducing the current that can be delivered to the ESP32.

It would help if you could solder a large value capacitor to the  ESP32 between the 5V and ground pins, but since you're playing with solderless breadboards it is unlikely you have a soldering iron.

Comment: would using a 9V 1A power supply instead of a battery solve the problem?

Comment: It would certainly help.  The resistance in the breadboard connections may still cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The connections are correct and it should work if given enough current.

But the 9V battery likely just can't provide the required current, the voltage drops and the ESP32 reboots, or experiences a brown-out and hangs.